# jQuery function that displays and hides content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have four boxes each with a data attribute that I use to target four other boxes which I display and hide. I kinda have the function working how I would like.

But say I click box `one` then box `two` they are both showing. What I would like is only the box which was clicked last to display while all the others hide. If box `one` is clicked the box for it will display, if it is clicked again it will hide.

This is what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click").click(function(){
  var current_sec = $(this).data("section");
    
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked")){
      $("#" + current_sec).removeClass("show");
      $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    } else{    
      $(this).addClass("clicked");
      $("#" + current_sec).addClass("show");
    }
    });  
});
```

```css
.click{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#one{
  background-color: blue;
}

#two{
  background-color: yellow;
}

#three{
  background-color: red;
}

#four{
  background-color: orange;
}

.sections{
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 18px;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.show{
  max-height: 1000px;
}

#section_1{
  background-color: blue;
}

#section_2{
  background-color: yellow;
}

#section_3{
  background-color: red;
}

#section_4{
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="click" data-section="section_1"></div>
<div id="two" class="click" data-section="section_2"></div>
<div id="three" class="click" data-section="section_3"></div>
<div id="four" class="click" data-section="section_4"></div>

<div class="sections" id="section_1">
  <div class="box"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat neque.</p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_2">
  <div class="box"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat neque.</p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_3">
  <div class="box"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat neque.</p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_4">
   <div class="box"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat neque.</p>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the *active* classes from `click` and `sections` *except* the *current* one by using [**`jQuery not()`**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$(".sections").not(this).removeClass("show");
$('.click').not(this).removeClass("clicked");
```

See demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click").click(function() {
    var current_sec = $(this).data("section");

    // remove active from other tabs
    $(".sections").not(this).removeClass("show");
    $('.click').not(this).removeClass("clicked");

    if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
      $("#" + current_sec).removeClass("show");
      $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("clicked");
      $("#" + current_sec).addClass("show");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.click {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#one {
  background-color: blue;
}

#two {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#three {
  background-color: red;
}

#four {
  background-color: orange;
}

.sections {
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 18px;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.show {
  max-height: 1000px;
}

#section_1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#section_2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#section_3 {
  background-color: red;
}

#section_4 {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="click" data-section="section_1"></div>
<div id="two" class="click" data-section="section_2"></div>
<div id="three" class="click" data-section="section_3"></div>
<div id="four" class="click" data-section="section_4"></div>

<div class="sections" id="section_1">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat
    magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat
    neque.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_2">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat
    magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat
    neque.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_3">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat
    magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat
    neque.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_4">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat
    magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat
    neque.
  </p>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `show` class whenever the boxes are cleared and secondly, because you need `show/hide`, you also need to remove `clicked` class in the `else` condition:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".click").click(function() {
    $('.sections.show').removeClass('show');
    var current_sec = $(this).data("section");
    if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
      $("#" + current_sec).removeClass("show");
      $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    } else {
      $('.click.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
      $(this).addClass("clicked");
      $("#" + current_sec).addClass("show");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.click {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#one {
  background-color: blue;
}

#two {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#three {
  background-color: red;
}

#four {
  background-color: orange;
}

.sections {
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 18px;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.show {
  max-height: 1000px;
}

#section_1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#section_2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#section_3 {
  background-color: red;
}

#section_4 {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="click" data-section="section_1"></div>
<div id="two" class="click" data-section="section_2"></div>
<div id="three" class="click" data-section="section_3"></div>
<div id="four" class="click" data-section="section_4"></div>

<div class="sections" id="section_1">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat
    magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat
    neque.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_2">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat
    magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat
    neque.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_3">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat
    magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat
    neque.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_4">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat
    magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat
    neque.
  </p>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your else as the first line, to remove the show class from any section that was previously shown.

```
//remove clicked from the previously clicked elements
$('.click.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
//remove show from the reviously shown sections
$('.sections.show').removeClass('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use straight CSS with showing and hiding.  No custom classes necessary.  This should be what you are looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click").click(function(){
  var current_sec = $(this).data("section");
      // hide all sections first
      $('.sections').css("display", "none");

      // find the clicked section id
      var clickedId = $(this).attr('data-section');
 
      // show clicked section
      $('#' + clickedId).css("display", "");
    });  
});
```

```css
.click{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#one{
  background-color: blue;
}

#two{
  background-color: yellow;
}

#three{
  background-color: red;
}

#four{
  background-color: orange;
}

.sections{
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.show{
  max-height: 1000px;
}

#section_1{
  background-color: blue;
}

#section_2{
  background-color: yellow;
}

#section_3{
  background-color: red;
}

#section_4{
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="click" data-section="section_1"></div>
<div id="two" class="click" data-section="section_2"></div>
<div id="three" class="click" data-section="section_3"></div>
<div id="four" class="click" data-section="section_4"></div>

<div class="sections" id="section_1">
  <div class="box"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat neque.</p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_2">
  <div class="box"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat neque.</p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_3">
  <div class="box"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat neque.</p>
</div>

<div class="sections" id="section_4">
   <div class="box"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi lobortis augue quis lectus sollicitudin venenatis. Vestibulum quam nisi, condimentum ac diam ut, aliquam dignissim odio. Nulla nulla arcu, convallis quis ipsum tempor, volutpat placerat magna. Praesent non neque maximus, sollicitudin eros vitae, mattis augue. Donec ac semper purus. Vivamus a elit eu risus porttitor mollis. Cras efficitur quam sed nisi facilisis volutpat. Mauris in arcu nec magna ullamcorper luctus. Cras non placerat neque.</p>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```